# Upload videos to youtube using youtube api by any remote user

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, video-upload

I'm trying to upload a video on youtube using google-api-php-client but after all the process I have done. I had to authorize following a link (authorize access) and on localhost its generating the error 400. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

and says,
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost/youtubeVideoUpload/upload.php, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs,;

I want to ask that 
Firstly how can I solve this issue;
Secondly Is there any way that I can authorize any remote user to upload video on my youtube channel using php

Authorization Required
You need to authorize access before proceeding.

Comment: You can't use localhost to test online API. You need first to publish your page on a webserver with real domain and an SSL certificate.

Comment: Okay @fox91 I'll try the code on online server then ask if any error occurs